# Can you capture what a user is currently listening to?

Tags: spotipy

I'm currently working on a project that detects when someone is listening to a song on Spotify and sends a message to that person based upon that song being in a playlist.

I couldn't see a spotipy function to get this data, even though I can see it on the spotify application itself, any pointers?

Comment: Seems they do have `currently_playing()` function, see https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.18.0/#api-reference. I think you simply overlooked it :)

Comment: Only works for the current user e.g. me

Answer (score 0):

Accessing friends' activity feed is something that many people have been requesting for a long time, however Spotify [does not seem to have any plan to open it up](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/83) unfortunately.

Currently, the only existing workaround I am aware of is to scrape the internal API used by the client, as is done here: https://github.com/valeriangalliat/spotify-buddylist

Another option for your project would be to use [last.fm APIs](https://www.last.fm/api/show/user.getRecentTracks) if the user is on it and you know the handle -- which is less than ideal of course.